# Why is Tor not visible in my Programs and Features in the Control Panel?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

After installing Tor (browser bundle) on my Win7-64 machine, it doesn't show up as an installed program in Programs and Features in the Control Panel? Is this normal or is this a glitch?

Answer (score 3):

Because the 'Installer' just decompresses a zip archive that's been created as a `.exe`.

To make it visible in the control panel you need a different type of installer that supports that feature.

Answer (score 3):

The Tor Project's information page on the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) states:

> The Tor Browser Bundle lets you use Tor on Windows, Mac OS X, or Linux
>   **without needing to install any software**. It can run off a USB flash
>   drive, comes with a pre-configured web browser to protect your
>   anonymity, and is self-contained.

It's meant to be *completely* portable. This means that when you download and unzip it (on Windows, Mac, or Linux) you're extracting a pre-compiled, ready-to-go executable. Each time you unzip it you're getting a fresh "install" so to speak, and all it would take to "uninstall" it would be to delete the folder containing it. The whole process of installing/uninstalling leaves as little trace on the operating system as possible.